# Dropbox restarts itself when computer is idle. Refuses to fully close

Tags: windows, dropbox

I use metered hotspots a lot and , I would like Dropbox to run and sync when I allow it. But if you disable it from auto-starting on boot, it will start itself regardless when my computer is idle. Here it is after I left my computer on overnight.

How can I fix this?
I've already tried fully uninstalling and  reinstalling dropbox.

[image: Dropbox autostarting itself]

I'm running Windows 10. `Dropbox v29.3.18`